# Getting the delegate to callback on successful login dropbox using REST api through GTMOAuth

Tags: ios, rest, oauth, restful-authentication, dropbox-api

I have used GTMOAuth to successfully login to dropbox but i dont seem to be able to get the delegate to callback once the response is returned 
I have this code to login ..

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token"];
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token"];
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize"];
NSString *scope = nil;

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self authForTwitter];
if (auth == nil) {
// perhaps display something friendlier in the UI?
 NSAssert(NO, @"A valid consumer key and consumer secret are required for signing in to Twitter");
}

// set the callback URL to which the site should redirect, and for which
// the OAuth controller should look to determine when sign-in has
// finished or been canceled
//
// This URL does not need to be for an actual web page; it will not be
// loaded
[auth setCallback:@"https://www.dropbox.com"];

NSString *keychainItemName = nil;
if ([self shouldSaveInKeychain]) {
  keychainItemName = kTwitterKeychainItemName;
}

// Display the autentication view.
GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
             language:nil
      requestTokenURL:requestURL
     authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
       accessTokenURL:accessURL
       authentication:auth
       appServiceName:keychainItemName
             delegate:self
     finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

// We can set a URL for deleting the cookies after sign-in so the next time
// the user signs in, the browser does not assume the user is already signed
// in
[viewController setBrowserCookiesURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.dropbox.com/"]];

// You can set the title of the navigationItem of the controller here, if you want.

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

I have tried editing the of the library but to no success .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumped into the same problem. After some debugging it seems the problem is that the callback URL is not included with the "6.2.1.  Consumer Directs the User to the Service Provider" step (http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step2). According to the OAuth specs it should not, but Dropbox requires it to do the redirect.

So to test, I changed GTMOAuthAuthentication.m like this:

```
+ (NSArray *)tokenAuthorizeKeys {
  // keys for opening the authorize page, http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step2
  NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   kOAuthTokenKey,
                   // extensions
                   kOAuthDomainKey,
                   kOAuthHostedDomainKey,
                   kOAuthLanguageKey,
                   kOAuthMobileKey,
                   kOAuthScopeKey,
                   kOAuthCallbackKey, // !pi! 20120313 dropbox testing
                   nil];
  return keys;
}
```

i.e. added the callback URL to this step as well. Now GTMOAuth works with Dropbox for me.

There should be a better solution of doing this, but I was just testing GTMOAuth/RESTKit and this was sufficient for me.